# Remove or delete folder on google drive base on list folder in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Helo

Im newbies on google script, I have a Google Drive folder list in Google Sheet, how do I delete folders on Google Drive based on the data on the Google sheet?

Comment: What information do you have about folders in the sheet?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: I Have Googledrive ID, Folder ID, File Name, Folder Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ID you can use the [getFolderByID() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) followed by the [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#settrashedtrashed) one.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //or getSheetByName() if necessary
var folderToDelete = sheet.getRange(<range of your folder IDs list>);
var folderIDs = folderToDelete.getValues();

folderIDs.forEach(function(id){
  DriveApp.getFolderByID(id).setTrashed(true);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Salix im following that code but return me _Missing ) after argument list. (line 9, file "Code")_ <br/>

Here's my code

<pre> function DeleteFile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  var folderToDelete = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1:A5');
  var folderIDs = folderToDelete.getValues();
  
  folderIDs.forEach(function(id){
  DriveApp.getFolderByID(id).setTrashed(true);
  };
  
} <code>

Comment: you're missing a ')'. (well I was). I'll edit, but it's after the .forEach bit. When you get those error, just check that every '(', '[' and '{' have their closing equivalent :)